# How do I delete a 'ghost' remote branch in Git?

Tags: git

When I

`git branch -a | grep my_funny_branch`

it gives

`remotes/origin/my_funny_branch`

But when I

`git branch -d -r origin/my_funny_branch`

it gives

`error: remote branch 'origin/my_funny_branch' not found`

and when I just

`git pull origin master`

I get

```
git pull origin master
From ssh://example.com/foo/bar
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch
Counting objects: 47339, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16489/16489), done.
Writing objects: 100% (47339/47339), done.
Total 47339 (delta 30622), reused 47339 (delta 30622)
Rename from '.git/objects/pack/.tmp-7576-pack-15e7c5d209199f384b04dd820a8d625c658f7402.pack' to '.git/objects/pack/pack-15e7c5d209199f384b04dd820a8d625c658f7402.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

How do I delete that remote branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This error message is interesting:

```
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch
```

Looking at the Git source code, that message appears when Git is processing the reflog for that ref.  It's possible the log is broken in some way, preventing various operations on the ref from completing successfully.

After backing it up, try deleting the log for that ref:

```
rm -rf .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch
```

and then see if you can delete the branch.

Comment: thx. it turns out that it just started working. Not sure what the case was. If I run into the problem again, I'll try this.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also has to delete .git/refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch.

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem.
Solution for me was as follows:

```
git remote prune origin
```

and then

```
git fetch --prune
```

Ended up having a list of about 20 ghost branches pruned down to only what is actually a live branch

Answer (score 5):

Try running `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch origin --prune`

[More Info Here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/my_funny_branch
```

If that doesn't work I would look for 'my_funny_branch' in your .git directory (probably .git/refs/remotes/origin) and see if there is something goofy with the file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
git push origin :my_funny_branch
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Thanks for posting.